# Generic type 'DataResponse' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2)

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire, alamofire-request

Updating to Alamofire 4.5 broke the syntax. How should I reformat my code in order for it to work?

What I have:

```
func getAllBeacons(completionHandler: @escaping ([BeaconModel]) -> ()) {
        let URL = "https://testwebapi.knowe.net/Knowe.Beacon.WebApi/beacon/GetAllByLanguage"
        let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]
        print(UIDevice.current.modelName)
        AF.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: ["SearchValue": preferredLanguage, "IosModelName": UIDevice.current.modelName]).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[BeaconModel]>) in
            let beaconArray = response.result.value
            completionHandler(beaconArray!)
        }
    }
```

What I had:

```
func getAllBeacons(completionHandler: @escaping ([BeaconModel]) -> ()) {
        let URL = "https://testwebapi.knowe.net/Knowe.Beacon.WebApi/beacon/GetAllByLanguage"
        let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]
        print(UIDevice.current.modelName)
        Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: ["SearchValue": preferredLanguage, "IosModelName": UIDevice.current.modelName]).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[BeaconModel]>) in
            let beaconArray = response.result.value
            completionHandler(beaconArray!)
        }
    }
```

Strangely this code works when I run it on the emulator, but not on my physical iPhones.
The latter gives me an error: Module 'Alamofire' has no member named 'request'

This project was asigned to me, and I don't know what versions of Alamofire and Alamofireobjectmapper were used. The best case scenario would be to downgrade to the former versions but I don't know what versions will be compatible with the former syntax.

I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 and Swift

```
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
  pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
  pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.11.4'
```

Answer (score 5):

Alamofire 5 changed the various `*Response` types to be doubly generic. That is, generic to both the `Success` and `Failure` types. In your case, your `DataResponse` needs to provide an `Error` type which is produced in failure cases. Alamofire 5 returns the `AFError` type by default, but since `responseArray` is custom, there may be different error types in use.

As an aside, the `pod` definitions you've provided should not have been able to upgrade to Alamofire 5, so I'm not sure how you've encountered this issue.

Comment: Any idea how to handle this doubly generic>

Comment: @Anuraj You can use the `AFDataResponse` or `AFDownloadResponse` type to make it singly generic with an `AFError` error type. But if you want a different error type you'll need to deal with both types.

Comment: In lower version of Alamofire i used this code request.response { (response:DataResponse<responseType>) in
  }. Where responseType was a generic. When using the latest one the following error is getting Generic type 'DataResponse' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2). And when I use this ----> request.response { (response:AFDataResponse<responseType>) in
        } getting error cannot convert value of type '(DataResponse<responseType, AFError>) -> ()' to expected argument type '(AFDataResponse<Data?>) -> Void' (aka '(DataResponse<Optional<Data>, AFError>)